# Cannot load image from some URL in Android devices (API < 20 ) using Picasso 2.5.2

Tags: android, url, imageview, picasso

Picasso loads images normally using Android (API > 20), but the problem is with API < 20 (can't load images from URL). Here is my code:

Java code:

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()).setLoggingEnabled(true);
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load("https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1701/M78_Tiziano_960.jpg").error(R.drawable.error_logo).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE).fit().into(img);
StatsSnapshot picassoStats = Picasso.with(getActivity()).getSnapshot();
Log.d("Picasso Stats", picassoStats.toString());
```

XML code:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/testImg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:contentDescription="@string/apod_img"
    />
```

Logcat:

```
D/Picasso: Main        created      [R0] Request{https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1701/M78_Tiziano_960.jpg resize(1080,900)}
D/Picasso Stats: StatsSnapshot{maxSize=57521883, size=0, cacheHits=0, cacheMisses=0, downloadCount=0, totalDownloadSize=0, averageDownloadSize=0, totalOriginalBitmapSize=0, totalTransformedBitmapSize=0, averageOriginalBitmapSize=0, averageTransformedBitmapSize=0, originalBitmapCount=0, transformedBitmapCount=0, timeStamp=1485260878562}
D/Picasso: Dispatcher  enqueued     [R0]+1ms 
D/Picasso: Hunter      executing    [R0]+2ms 
D/Picasso: Dispatcher  retrying     [R0]+1453ms
D/Picasso: Hunter      executing    [R0]+1453ms 
D/Picasso: Dispatcher  retrying     [R0]+2886ms
D/Picasso: Hunter      executing    [R0]+2887ms
D/Picasso: Dispatcher  batched      [R0]+2888ms for error
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 601K, 2% free 35220K/35884K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 41.415MB for 7300812-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5K, 2% free 42344K/43016K, paused 6ms, total 6ms
D/Picasso: Dispatcher  delivered    [R0]+3113ms
D/Picasso: Main        errored      [R0]+3133ms
```

Comment: Oddly, NASA is using a Let's Encrypt SSL cert, and it's possible that's not recognized as a root on older devices. You might try making an HTTP request of that URL using something else (OkHttp, `HttpURLConnection`, etc.) and see what sort of exception you get.

Comment: ok, thank you! ( same problem with glide )

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Just before

```
<Application
```

I suppose that you have the following lines of Code in your getView()

```
View rowView = mInflater.inflate(..., ..., ...);

ImageView img = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.testImg);
```

before

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load("https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1701/M78_Tiziano_960.jpg").error(R.drawable.error_logo).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE).fit().into(img);
```